При вводе чисел с плавающей точкой все ломается
Недавно начал учить C. Решал задачу с циклом. При вводе чисел с плавающей точкой все ломается, цикл не может закончиться, при вводе целочисленных все нормально
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int number = 0;
    float start_balance, whole_sum_wastes, whole_credit_sum, max_credit, balance;
    while (number != -1)
    {
        printf("Введите номера счёта (-1 если ввод закончен):\n");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        printf("Введите начальный баланс:\n");
        scanf("%f", &start_balance);
        printf("Введите общую сумму расходов:\n");
        scanf("%f", &whole_sum_wastes);
        printf("Введите общую сумму кредита:\n");
        scanf("%f", &whole_credit_sum);
        printf("Введите предельный размер кредита:\n");
        scanf("%f", &max_credit);
        printf("Счёт: %d\n", number);
        printf("Предельный размер кредита: %f\n", max_credit);
        balance = start_balance + whole_sum_wastes - whole_credit_sum;
        printf("Баланс: %f\n", balance);
        if (balance > max_credit)
            printf("Предельный размер кредита превышен\n");
        else
            printf("Предельный размер кредита не превышен\n");
    }
}


Не распознаётся точка.
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C"); // Установи символ десятичной точки на точку

Просто ты локаль "Russian" указываешь, запятой отделяем...
